# How to get jQuery datepicker to show months even while using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a page that includes a jQuery datepicker and I include the bootstrap CSS files, which helps the display look better.  However, the months and years are not showing like in this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929883/not-showing-data-in-month-and-year-dropdown-in-datepicker)

I don't want to remove the bootstrap files to fix the problem.  Is there any way to fix it while still including them?

```
 <td>DOB - Age:</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Dob, new { id = "txtdob", style = "width:100px"}) <br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Dob)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { id = "txtAge", style = "width:30px"})<br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Age)
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>

 //birth date - no future dates and go back 100 years, set age
    $("#txtdob").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-100:+0",
        maxDate: '+0d',
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var dob = new Date(date);
            var today = new Date();
            var age = today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();
            $("#txtAge").val(age);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: analyze the css of  your months dropdown with firebug or another debugging tool. I suppose you will see that the color:style may be overwritten by bootstrap css

Comment: @Nameismy - I'm having the exact same problem as in the link I provided.

Comment: @MarioA - Unfortunately, I cannot use tools like that here, not allowed.  So I am stuck with trying to figure it out manually.  I saw the answer in the link, but I don't know where to apply that code.

Comment: Then just share your code the problem might be the same as someone had already but the code  can differ

Comment: @Nameismy - OK there is my code

Comment: @Dean.DePue you can use your browswers default debugging console, normally you open it using the F12 key

Comment: @MarioA - yes, I did that but I don't see any CSS stuff only html.

Comment: check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ravanliyski/hnu0r78y/7/)